# Passing in dynamic variables into buildspec file of codebuild

Tags: aws-codebuild

Is there a way to pass dynamic variables into the buildspec file of code build?

For example

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build --build-arg user_email=aaa -t a .
```

sometimes the user_email can be bbb or ccc or eee and Setting the environment variable in codebuild is static.

Comment: From where do these e-mails (dynamic variables) come from?

Comment: they will be coming from a form in my web portal

Comment: You could put the e-mail into SQS and trigger the Codebuild to fetch the e-mails from the queue. When the build has succeeded, delete the message from the queue. Just make sure to set the VisibilityTimeout high enough for the build to be able to succeed without returning the message to the queue.

I am also not sure if Codebuild is the best solution for you but I do not know your use-case. Just make sure to validate user-input etc.